# What to say when my request is declined

Tags: word-choice, expressions, email

I asked something about my assignment to my professor by email and she declined it because it is not fair to give more chances only to one person.
How can I respond to this email politely and show her that I get what she said and I'm totally okay with it?
Is there any better way (more polite and sincere) than " Okay, thank you" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indicate that you have listened to and accept what the other person says by saying something like:

> Put like that, it seems reasonable.
>
> When you put it like that, I understand your position.
>
> I'm sorry, I hadn't considered it from that point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your prompt reply to my request. I had not considered that the request would give me an unfair advantage. So most of all thank you for trying to maintain a fair environment for the all the students in the class.